# Sencha Touch i18n

Tags: sencha-touch

I am attempting to implement the i18n strategy outlined [here](http://elmasse.gaver.nl/index.php/blog/4-posts/12-sencha-touch-bundles) in my Sencha Touch MVC app. The problem is, this strategy requires an onReady(), which I don't have anywhere in my app. I have an app.js, which defines a launch function. I've got a viewport which creates my various panels in my app's namespace. But creating the Bundle object in either of these doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas, or maybe a different approach I should be taking to i18n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earliest event would be

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
      ...
    }
});
```

That onReady will fire when the dom is ready before your application exists ... but from the example that [Ext.i18n.Bundle-touch provides](https://github.com/elmasse/Ext.i18n.Bundle-touch/blob/master/js/test.js) they are calling the bundle.onReady function in the launch function.